# AngularJs $scope.$destroy(). How to use?

Tags: angularjs, performance, memory-leaks, angularjs-scope, heap-memory

I am analyzing the code of my application AngularJs to try Maximising performance and i put this code in my controller

```
$scope.$on("$destroy", () ->
  console.log "DESTROY SCOPE OF CONTROLLER BEFORE EXIT"
  console.log window.performance.memory
  $scope.$destroy()
  console.log window.performance.memory
)
```

So

```
$scope.$destroy()
```

should clear the scope of my controller and its children.
The problem is that when I leave the controller and activates the event $ destroy, in console I see that the logs are in the loop. Why?

[image]

Thank you all

Comment: The destroy event is emitted when the scope is being destroyed. And you destroy the scope in the event listener. So that emits a destroy event, which calls the listener, which destroys the scope, which emits an event, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a part of the answer in the documentation concerning [scope life cycle](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle).

In your case you're calling the $destroy event in the listener. So you're doing a recursive call of the $destroy event.